# MySQL simple join using temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I've got (what I thought) was a very simple query on a MySQL database, but using `explain` shows that the query is using a temporary table. I've tried changing the order of the select and the join but to no avail. I've reduced the tables to their simplest (to see if it was an issue with the complexity of my tables, but I still have the problem). I've tried it with two basic tables, one with a "name" field, and the other with a foreign key reference back to that table:

```
a:
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(128) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

b:
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| a_id  | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id ORDER BY a.name;
```

Which I thought was very simple... just a list of all records in `a` that have records in `b`, ordered by name. Alas `explain` says this:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref    | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | index  | a_id          | a_id    | 4       | NULL   |    2 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | b.a_id |    1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

It looks like it should be using the key on the `b` table but for some reason it isn't. I get the feeling I'm missing something basic (or my RDBMS knowledge needs brushing up somewhat). Anyone any ideas why it's using a temporary table for such a simple query?

Comment: Could you give the scripts you used to create the tables you're using, including indexes and constraints? There might be something about the indexes and/or foreign key that is causing this.

Comment: And this is a problem because ... ?

Comment: @Robert - I used phpMyAdmin - exporting the tables gives this:     

    CREATE TABLE a (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      KEY `name` (`name`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE b (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      a_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      KEY a_id (a_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: @DaleM - I understood that if it was using temporary tables for a query that it was a performance problem (especially if the table has a large number of records) - is this not the case then?

Comment: Not necessarilly, the optimiser has decided in this case that the temporary table is the best option. If you have an index on `a.id` `b.a_id` and `a.name` then there is no further optimisation possible. Bear in mind that the temporary table may be a memory construct - it is not neccesarily disk resident. If it is in memory then writing and accessing it is quick.

Comment: @DaleM - ah ok, that makes sense - those indices do indeed exist, so I can see how it can't be optimised further. I haven't had a performance problem with it yet, I was just concerned that as the table grows it might become a problem. (I'll accept your answer if you put it as an answer) Thanks!

Comment: As the table grows the optimiser may choose a different method. Optimisation considers the estimated row count.